# boto3 - get all required API calls for a specific method in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Given a service name and list of actions, I need to find out which API calls are required in the boto3 method. suggestions?

I've tried for example getting a code object of the boto3 code and examine there through something like :

```
iam = boto3.client('iam')

code = iam.list_roles.__code__
```

but even if i have the exact location of the call, can't find what API calls are required (HTTP-Post/ GET / etc..)

Comment: The boto3 client-level method names closely match the underlying AWS API (e.g. ec2.run_instances() => RunInstances). But, boto3 also provides higher-level abstractions over the APIs, so a given method can make multiple API calls. What's your underlying goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I found that every service client has an  '.meta.method_to_api_mapping' field
that return exactly what i meant.